# analyticsDataClient.runReport returning null on querying from GA

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get data from my Google Analytics account(v4) through a nodeJs API.

This is my code

```
const getApGaData = async (propertyId = "259735053") => {
  const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
  const response = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: "2021-02-20",
        endDate: "today",
      },
    ],
    dimensions: [
      {
        name: "date",
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: "activeUsers",
      },
    ],
  });
  console.log(response);
};
getApGaData()
```

This is my .env file

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./google-services.json"
```

The response I am getting is

```
[ [ { name: 'date' } ], null, null ]
```

I am unable to figure out the mistake I am making. I have created a GCP project, enable GA Data API, created service credentials, added the service email to my GA giving access.

Comment: There is a bug in the rollout of the Beta client. The alpha client works. Please use v2.1.0 until it is fixed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-analytics/data/v/2.1.0